# how to feed strings in an empty list?

Tags: python, excel, list

I am trying to store the values obtained from excel sheet cells to a list. The code provided basically collects data from different continuous rows and columns and creates a string of those values. I could work upt o storing the string value but I don't really know how to store the strings in a list, Can anyone help me with this?

```
for i in range(NR):
    print("This TC checks the output for")
    for j in range(NC):
        inputVariable = str(ws[get_column_letter(ColumnStart+j) + str(rowStart-1)].value)
        c = str((ws.cell(row = (rowStart + i),column = (ColumnStart +j)).value))
        if (ws.cell(row = (rowStart + i),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value) == (ws.cell(row = (MaxValRow),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value):
            b = '(maximum)'
        elif (ws.cell(row = (rowStart + i),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value) == (ws.cell(row = (MinValRow),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value):
            b = '(minimum)'
        else:
            b ='(intermediate)'
        Commentstr = str(j+1) + '. The value of input ' + inputVariable + ' =' + " " + c + b
        # need to create a list here to store the commentstr for each iteration
```

NR = no. of rows, NC = no. of columns

Comment: Initialize `Commentstr` as a list: `Commentstr = []` and then use `Commentstr.append(...)`. Please read the section in pydoc about lists: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: @Ronald. Thank you I tried some online sites and I was facing the issue, I tried your way. and it works. Thank you! if I want it to be printed in the same order in a separate function, how to do that? l have written the code and given the range but the output is not in the same sequence!

Comment: I  found out how to do that, was doing a dumb mistake. my bad, thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=[]
for i in range(NR):
    x=0
    print("This TC checks the output for")
    for j in range(NC):
        inputVariable = str(ws[get_column_letter(ColumnStart+j) + str(rowStart-1)].value)
        c = str((ws.cell(row = (rowStart + i),column = (ColumnStart +j)).value))
        if (ws.cell(row = (rowStart + i),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value) == (ws.cell(row = (MaxValRow),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value):
            b = '(maximum)'
        elif (ws.cell(row = (rowStart + i),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value) == (ws.cell(row = (MinValRow),column = (ColumnStart+j)).value):
            b = '(minimum)'
        else:
            b ='(intermediate)'
        Commentstr = str(j+1) + '. The value of input ' + inputVariable + ' =' + " " + c + b
        my_list[x]=Commentstr
        x+=1
```

Comment: That won't work in Python (perhaps in other programming languages...). my_list[0] produces an IndexError if my_list is empty.

Comment: @Ronald : that's why my_list=[ ] is created above...

Comment: I did see that, but `my_list=[]` is an 'empty' list which does not have index [0]. You can try it in the Python interpreter.